# How to get ViewPager's current View which is the one show to user in onPageSelected

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I use this way to get ViewPager's current View :

```
private class OuterAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private SwipingVideoPage currentPage;

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        SwipingVideoPage page = new SwipingVideoPage();
        container.addView(page);
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        currentPage = (SwipingVideoPage)object;
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public SwipingVideoPage getCurrenPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }
}
```

I think I can call `ViewPager.getAdapter.getCurrentPage()` to get current view. But I found it's not work in `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected()`:

```
private class OuterChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        ((OuterAdapter)outerViewPager.getAdapter()).getCurrenPage()  //this returns the previous shown view, not the right one
    }
}
```

Maybe the `onPageSelected()` is called before `setPrimaryItem()`, is this correct ?

And how to get `ViewPage`'s primary view in `onPageSelected()` ?

Comment: do you want complete view or just position of that view

Comment: I need the complete view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as @Mohammad Fareed said, I didn't find a method to get the current page directly in `ViewPager`.

So I use this way to solve the problem:

```
private Map<Integer, View> pageMap;     //records all the pages in the ViewPager
private SwipingVideoPage currentPage;

private class OuterAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        SwipingVideoPage page = new SwipingVideoPage();
        container.addView(page);
        pageMap.put(position, page);    //add page
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
        pageMap.remove(position);      //remove page which is removed from ViewPager
    }
}

private class OuterChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPage = pageMap.get(position);    //get current page
    }
}
```

I use these code in my project, and it works great until now.

Answer (score -2):

in the latest packages you can also use

```
vp.getCurrentItem()
```

or

```
vp is the viewPager ,

pageListener = new PageListener();
vp.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
```

you have to put a page change listener for your viewPager. There is no method on viewPager to get the current page.

private int currentPage;

```
private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.i(TAG, "page selected " + position);
               currentPage = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can get the current position, but what I want is the View which is shown to users. Is there no way to get the current View?

Comment: You have not answered the question. He is interested in View, not in the position number.